# How can I create a git commit with just a comment?

Tags: git, commit

I wonder if it is possible to create a git commit that consists just of a comment, without any actual file changes.

This could be useful when doing code reviews when people just vote on a commit/branch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use:

```
git commit --allow-empty
```

From the [`git-commit(1)` man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html):

> **--allow-empty**
>              Usually recording a commit that has the exact same tree as its sole
>              parent commit is a mistake, and the command prevents you from
>              making such a commit. This option bypasses the safety, and is
>              primarily for use by foreign SCM interface scripts.

But are you sure you don't actually just want a tag?

Comment: Darn I went through just that page, and totally missed that option. Thanx.

Comment: @JensSchauder, really why not `git tag` or `git notes`? I'm sure you're going to misuse `git commit`.

Comment: @kostix git tag would be the wrong tool. I'm not marking a commit for later use (which is for me the purpose of a tag). Notes look like a good alternative, never heard about them before. The difference seem to be that notes can be changed at any time, while a commit cannot be changed ... Not sure which one fits my need more. Thanks for the hint

Comment: @JensSchauder, tags have two purposes: "simple" (not unannotated) tags are usually served as sort of bookmarks to commits. Annotated tags are for essentially the same thing *but* also to attach additional meaning to commits, and that's why they're typically used for designating releases (milestones) of the piece of software being managed with Git. Annotated tags might not only contain a message but can also be cryptographically single. Calls like `git tag --points-at` might be used to list all tags pointing to a commit. To me, looks like exactly what you need.